# Is there a way to "test" the use of "volatile" keyword in C on a Desktop computer running Linux or Windows?

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, volatile

I know that 'volatile' keyword in C is used to tell the compiler to NOT load the variable from RAM memory into a register or into cache and to ALWAYS read the variable from the computer working memory.

However I also read that the use case is when another device is modifying the value at the memory address stored in the variable.

My question is:

Is there any possibility to modify the value of a memory address while a program is running on a Linux or a Windows machine that also has a MMU and uses virtual address space for its programs (like all modern machines)?

Is it possible to change a variable of a program from another program (running in a different process not only a different thread) ?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any possibility to modify the value of a memory address while a program is running on a Linux or a Windows machine that also has a MMU and uses virtual address space for its programs (like all modern machines)?

Yes, of course!

The obvious example is threading: another thread could be updating the memory you're looking at, so you don't want to assume it never changes.

Other examples include:

- Shared memory. Processes can agree to share a piece of memory for efficient IPC.
- `mmap`.  A program can map a file into memory. When the file changes, the corresponding memory also changes (on Linux, this is the basis of shared memory).
- DMA. Other devices, like hard drives, can be asked to write data directly to RAM for efficient transfers.

> Is it possible to change a variable of a program from another program (running in a different process not only a different thread) ?

Yes. If the processes agree, you can use shared memory.

If they don't, one can attach itself to another as a debugger and inspect/modify its memory.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of questions here, so I'll tackle the first. "...test the use of volatile keyword..."

I suppose you could compile the module without the volatile keyword down to assembler (I believe it is the -S option). The method could be repeated for the same code modified with the volatile keyword, then a diff tool could put a spotlight on the changes. I would suspect the loading of the variable in question with the volatile keyword would always be directly from the location of it. 
This could also be verified by looking at the .map listing to know in advance what the actual location of the volatile variable is so you have a basis for comparison.